# "Use of undefined constant" error while trying to display image in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, image, codeigniter, base-url

I'm new to codeigniter and I'm facing a problem when trying to display an image.

Here's my code:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(images/sty2.png);?>" alt="">
```

This is the error message:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: **Use of undefined
>   constant sty2 - assumed 'sty2'** Filename: views/index.php Line Number:
>   195 Backtrace: File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMSON\application\views\index.php Line: 195 Function:
>   _error_handler File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMSON\application\controllers\Home.php Line: 31
>   Function: view File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMSON\index.php Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

How do I fix this?

Comment: pass complete image url from controller side

Comment: `A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Use of undefined constant sty2 - assumed 'sty2' Filename: views/index.php Line Number: 195 Backtrace: File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMSON\application\views\index.php Line: 195 Function: _error_handler File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMSON\application\controllers\Home.php Line: 31 Function: view File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAMSON\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once`

Comment: this error im getting

Comment: did not got u @DevsiOdedra

Comment: thanks it worked.... thank you for ur suggestion

Comment: i have one more issue. the font awesome which i'm using in my project is not displaying, i mean to say its displaying in square box. please can u help me out with this one as well ? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/fontawesome-all.css">` i have used like this in my header section but its not working for font awesome

Comment: @pavankumar Can you not use the same syntax? `echo base_url("css/fontawesome-all.css");`

Comment: its not working @mickmackusa i tried this yesterday itself

Comment: Then it seems to be a path problem which I cannot assist with.  Check the difference in directories between  `images/sty2.png` versus `css/fontawesome-all.css` Investigate from there.

Comment: im using such code of font awesome  `.fa-asymmetrik:before {
  content: "\f372"; }` @mickmackusa

Comment: Sorry, I am supporting another user right now.  This is a separate issue.  You are welcome to post another question if you like or continue researching.

Comment: ok sure no problem @mickmackusa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use codeigniter, but according to https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html your syntax seems correct with the exception of the missing quotes.

```
echo base_url("images/sty2.png");
```

Did you load the helper?

Something like: `$this->load->helper('url');`